# Positioning of cell according to the hight of previous cell in collection view in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, storyboard

I am working on a wallpaper app with images of different sizes. I am calculating the sizes of cells dynamically with respect to image size. But how I can set the positions of cells dynamically with respect to its upper cell .. see the screenshots below:

[image: Wallpaper App]

**How can I create a dynamic layout like this.. see screenshot:**

[image: Wallpaper app]

Comment: As you yourself have implied, you would need to write a custom layout.